# Функция с неопределенным кол-вом аргументов-ссылок

Tags: php, ссылки

Собственно сабж, писал тут функцию рекурсивной stripslashes, подумалось, что неплохо было бы записать ее одним вызовом. Но: если аргумент один, все нормально

```
function a(&$link) {
  $link = 'a';
  }
```

Если больше, начинаются проблемы:

```
function upcase() {
  $args = &func_get_args();
  foreach ($args as &$arg)
    $arg = strtoupper($arg);
  }
$a = $b = $c = 'lol';
upcase(&$a, $b, $c); // &$a выдаст ворнинг, в большинстве случаев allow_call_pass_time_reference выключен. Но и в обратном случае не отработает)
var_dump($a, $b, $c); // 'lol', 'lol', 'lol'...
```

Пока нашел такое решение:

```
function upcase(&$args) {
  if (is_array($args)) {
    foreach ($args as &$arg)
      upcase($arg);
    } else $args = strtoupper($args);
  }
upcase($a = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_REQUEST));
var_dump($_GET);
```

Но по-моему решение грязное и пошлое.

Есть предложения?

Comment: А будет ли ссылкой переменная $tmp, если:

    $tmp=&$link;

?

Comment: Да, будет указывать туда же, что `$link`. Но при передаче в функцию все равно скопируется)

Comment: Есть подозрения, что из func_get_args из ссылок формирует новый массив и передает его $args. В итоге ссылки теряются. Проверьте - внутри функции все работает.

Comment: @ling, тоже так думаю. Вопрос, как бы обойти, а то как-то некрасиво) Руками прописывать сотню необязательных тоже стремно))

Внутри-то да, трейсил... Но упорно не присваивает внешнему значению.

Comment: Я все еще не против, если кто-то предложит еще варианты) А то я накопал странные какие-то...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пара часов гугления дали такой результат. Он не идеален, но работоспособен)

```
<?
/*
вариант раз: дикий хак, 
но почти приятный в употреблении.
если честно, даже не вникаю в подробности
требуется включенный allow_call_pass_time_reference
собственно, по памяти-скорости только он представляет
интерес, ибо #2 жрет как конь)
*/
function upcase() {
  $stack = debug_backtrace();
  foreach ($stack[0]["args"] as &$arg)
    $arg = strtoupper($arg);
  }
$a = $b = $c = 'lol';
upcase(&$a, &$b, &$c);
var_dump($a, $b, $c);
echo '<br />';
/*
вариант 2 - почти не хак,
но чуть менее удобен и сильно более затратен 
в техническом плане(все копируется дважды)
+ абсолютно прозрачен
*/
function upcase2() {
  $result = array();
  foreach (func_get_args() as $arg)
    $result[] = strtoupper($arg);
  return $result;
  }
$a = $b = $c = 'lol';
list($a, $b, $c) = upcase2($a, $b, $c);
var_dump($a, $b, $c);
/*
Результат работы:
string(3) "LOL" string(3) "LOL" string(3) "LOL"
string(3) "LOL" string(3) "LOL" string(3) "LOL"

*/
?>
```

Comment: Ух. Что то мне кажется что для больших систем первый вариант будет очень ресурсоемким для такого типа задачи. Но решение мне понравилось :) Находчивое :)

Answer (score 0):

Оооооо!!!!! Наконец-то стоящий вопрос!

Дело в том что в php нельзя вернуть ссылку на простые типы.

Для теста напишем пару строк кода:

```
function proxy(&$a)
{
    $b = &$a;
    return $b;
}

$a1 = 'aaa';
echo $a1."\n";
$a2 = proxy($a1);
$a2 = 'zzz';
printf("[%s][%s]\n", $a1, $a2);

echo "Test class\n";

class TestProxy { public $t = ''; public function __construct($t){ $this->t = $t; } }

$b1 = new TestProxy('aaa');
echo $b1->t."\n";
$b2 = proxy($b1);
$b2->t = 'zzz';
printf("[%s][%s]\n", $b1->t, $b2->t);
```

А теперь проанализируем вывод:

`aaa
[aaa][zzz]
Test class
aaa
[zzz][zzz]`

Comment: В первом случае некорректно ;) Ссылки возвращаются по-другому:

    function &proxy(&$a){ // принимаем ссылку, возвращаем ссылку
      $b = &$a; // иначе скопирует
      return $b;
      }
    
    $a1 = 'aaa';
    $a2 = &proxy($a1); // принимаем ссылку. Да, я знаю, выглядит адски, но так уж устроен php) Если надо, найду момент в мануале
    $a2 = 'zzz';
    printf("[%s][%s]\n", $a1, $a2); // [zzz][zzz] 

А во втором - сложные типы просто по умолчанию передаются по ссылке. В моем случае проблема скорее в том, о чем сказал @ling.

Comment: Кстати, и для объектов это сработает. Чтобы принятый по ссылке объект **не** возвращать ссылкой, его нужно скопировать

    function a(&$a) { $b = $a; return $b; }

Тоже много канители с этой темой за плечами)

Comment: Согласен, про передачу ссылок из функции загнул.

Собственно я к тому, что бы вернуть ссылку функция должна быть объявлена соответствующим образом. И что-то я сомневаюсь что func_get_args так объявлена.

Comment: ..."пару строк"...